# How to type hexadecimal values in serial terminal?

Tags: hex, putty, serial-communication

I been trying to send raw hex values in serial programs such as Putty, MobaXterm, ComTestSerial and Minicom but I only manage to send the hex values in ComTestSerial by using format:

```
\x11\x52
```

but how I can write those hexadecimal values on the fly in Minicom for example? Do I have to write the command in hex values, binary values, dec values or ascii values or some combination of these?

ComTestSerial formats the command as:

```
{XON}R
```

but writing that straight to the terminal does not seem to help. The serial device responds after receiving those hex values.